# Vectors are parallel if one is a scalar multiple of the other

Tags: vectors

Vector $u$ and $v$ are parallel if and only if $u=cv$ for some scalar $c$

Can someone please begin the proof so i have an idea.

Comment: You might try drawing a picture.

Comment: Usually this is the definition of parallel vectors.  Do  you have some different definition?

Comment: No, we used this definition in class too without much question of it as its is pretty intuitive however I am asked to prove it @EmilioNovati

Comment: what definition do you use?

Comment: This is the definition we use but we are being asked to prove it so im not sure what to do @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: to prove a definition?

Comment: exactly im confused too